# Workflow `GITHUB_TOKEN` not authorised to download packages from GitHub registry

Tags: github, github-actions, yarn-v2

Following this [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication), I'm using the default `GITHUB_TOKEN` secret to download & publish packages from another repository of mine (same scope) on GitHub registry, from a workflow. Yarn is configured to use the environment variable `GITHUB_TOKEN`. When using the default `GITHUB_TOKEN` secret, I get a `403 (Forbidden)` error when downloading the package.

When using a PAT (a secret named `TOKEN` that I define manually with `write:packages` right), it works fine, when not using any token, I get a different error. Therefore, I assume the token is well transmitted and there is a right issue.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Here is my repository settings (`Actions` > `General`) :

- `Allow all actions and reusable workflows`: Any action or reusable workflow can be used, regardless of who authored it or where it is defined.
- `Read & write permissions`: Workflows have read and write permissions in the repository for all scopes.

Here is a test workflow ([link here](https://github.com/benjamin-guibert/test-token/actions/runs/4092234122)):

```yaml
name: Test Token

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  # Fail
  github:
    name: Test GitHub Token
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout the repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn install
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  # Success
  pat:
    name: Test PAT
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout the repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn install
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
```

Comment: That PAT has `packages: read` access too?

Comment: Yes, and it works fine, the issue is with `GITHUB_TOKEN`.

Comment: Right. You are referring to the default `GITHUB_TOKEN`, right? You want the default one instead of PAT?

Comment: Exactly. For the sake of example, I added `TOKEN` as a secret, nothing else. I run two jobs to show that `TOKEN` (manually added) is working but not the default `GITHUB_TOKEN`. I'm going to edit my post with that update.